# Payment Buttons bitcoin api

Tags: api, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway, bitcoin

I am using Payment Buttons api and it work successfully.

I created two account and generate button for one account and log out from this account. Now i am signing in from my other account and run application.

Here is my code generate from https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/payment_buttons

```
<a class="coinbase-button" data-code="92a06069482ddd972469a37e817608ee" data-button-style="custom_large" href="https://coinbase.com/checkouts/92a06069482ddd972469a37e817608ee">Pay With Bitcoin</a><script src="https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But, when i pay then i get this issue

[image]

Kindly tell me where is i wrong and aslo tell me how to create developer account or tell me how to use this api if i am wrong and tell me the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the account you are testing does not have enough funds! Double check to make sure that there is atleast 0.02 in there.

There is no "Dev" account yet. You pretty much have to test it out with your real Bitcoins.